# How do I send durable messages with Grails?

Tags: grails, message-queue, messaging, esb

Disclaimer: .Net guy trying to learn grails.

I've gotten used to building services with a distributed and durable messaging layer for inter-service communication with NServiceBus and MSMQ.

For anyone unfamiliar, NServiceBus provides messaging simply by referencing the assembly, doing some quick dependency injection.

Then, to work with it, I can send a message simply by doing something like `bus.Send("location", messageObject)` for a command, and `bus.publish(messageObject)` for a publish/subscribe situation. Then, all I have to do is create  a service that "listens" for my messageObject type and I get the message.

It also provides something they call timeouts - which basically will trigger some event handler after x amount of time (useful for sending reminders or doing something on a schedule).

I'm looking for something similar. I found an article that suggest using grails itself as an ESB, but I don't see how grails can provide reliable and durable messaging. What I mean by that - if service A sends a message to service B, and service B is down, service A will retry later. A more involved example would be that of a saga - where the client starts a saga, service A does something, and service B does something, both report to the saga when they're done processing, and then the saga sends a message to service C so it can do its thing, knowing that both service A and B have done their job.

PS: if this question is too broad, please let me know how I can refine it. I'm at the very beginning of learning grails, so I'm not even sure where I need to start researching stuff.

EDIT: realized I forgot to add the article- http://jlorenzen.blogspot.com/2009/03/grails-create-app-esb

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use some AMQP queue that has a Grails plugin (like RabbitMQ).

While this wouldn't give you all the features of NServiceBus on MSMQ, you would get the durable messaging behavior you wanted. Things you'd give up / have to implement yourself include some of the retry logic, sagas, and message idempotence.